# How to whitelist Facebook's OAuth page only?

Tags: facebook, oauth, ip, whitelist

I need to create a white list of IP addresses for Facebook OAuth web page and all its resources such as styles, scripts, images etc (so it is rendered nicely and works correctly). Also, the white list should not include other Facebook services. Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Not possible. Facebook may use any of the IP address they own. + any Akamai address for CDN

Comment: Does that mean that the only possible solution would be something like content filtering?

Comment: I'm saying don't even try to do it

Comment: Looked at your profile at SO and you know... I trust your opinion :)